# Converting ZX Spectrum .ipf files to .z80 or .tzx for use in Fuse on RetroPie?

Tags: emulation, zx-spectrum, file-format, software-recommendation

I have a 'perfect' set of ZX Spectrum games (in .ipf format) that I would like to use in EmulationStation (RetroPie) but the Fuse emulator doesn't recognize .ipf files.

Are there any tools that will convert .ipf files to a format that will work on said emulator?

Comment: IPF format is not by any means the preferred format for preserving ZX Spectrum files. AFAIK, IPF is for Amiga disk images, nothing to do with the Spectrum, and besides, most Spectrum software are tape images (TAP, TZX or PZX) which are well supported in Fuse. Are you sure those IPFs are for the Spectrum?

Comment: Or maybe you have a set of Amiga disk images that contains files in TAP, Z80 or whatever format the Amiga Spectrum emulator used?

Comment: (minor fyi to post editor: ‘recognise´ is a perfectly acceptable British English spelling and didn't need correcting)

Comment: @scruss I was considering a meta post about not correcting perfectly good US/UK/CDN/Intl. English spelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not currently. SPS's [IPF Support Library](http://www.softpres.org/download) is only distributed as a binary, and is not provided for ARM as used by Retropie.

IPF for ZX Spectrum +3 is supported by the commercial [Spectaculator](http://www.spectaculator.com/) emulator for Windows.